# Extract flutter's CustomScrollView elements into a widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to extract 2 Slivers elements into a separate Widget. But can't achieve that... Any ideas?
This is the original code:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: false,
      delegate: WidgetOne(),
    ),
    SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: WidgetTwo(),
    ),
    WidgetThree(),
  ],
)
```

The idea is to have something like this:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: false,
      delegate: WidgetOne(),
    ),
    ExtractedWidget()
  ],
)

class ExtractedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return .... 
    // What should be here? Containers etc returns error...
    SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: WidgetTwo(),
    ),
    WidgetThree(),
  }
}
```

Thanks!
PS: The whole logic of this code is that on the first place is some fixed height block, below there's one more with some height and the last one is *list* with various number of elements. The thing is that while scrolling the **second** block should be pinned. That's why I've used this slivers things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the sliver only like this example:

```
class ExtractedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: WidgetTwo(),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to return a tree of widget you will have to find a container that can hold that widgets, for example `SliverToBoxAdapter`, but i dont know if the `SliverPersistentHeader` can be placed inside another sliver container. Hope it can help.